# iOS >> CoreData >> How to find the Specific App Folder?

Tags: ios, core-data, directory

I'm trying to find an App folder in which the SQLite file was created.
I already have access to hidden "Library" folder and navigated to the relevant iPhone Simulator version folder.

Now I see a folder with all my apps but the folders names are some codes that look like this:

[image]

Which element in my specific app should I copy to search this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use this codes, App does it for you. Use:

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *sqlitePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.sqlite"];
```

Answer (score 1):

[SimPholders](http://simpholders.com/) should help in this case.